# Wrap text which does not fit page instead of moving it below others

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place elements in my header. I would like to have 3 elements inline - button, image and simple text. The height of the header should be equal height of image. All elements should be centered vertically. Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="btn">
        ...
    </div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <span style="float:none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
```

On image "a" I present expected behavior. On image "b" and "c" my results were shown. 
So, the expected result is to wrap text if it doesn't fit the page. But it still should be on the right side.

Legend:

- red rectangle - button
- orange rectangle - image

[image]

Does anyone know what styles I should use?

Comment: Have you tried a javascript `if statement` to change the `text-align` to `text-align: right`?

Comment: I would like to use pure HTML/CSS without javascript

Comment: To change a style based on somethings width is going to require javascript or media queries(which is css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make them:

> display: inline-block

Here is pretty simple demo:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn">...</div>
    <img src="http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504stolze/test_1.jpg" /> 
    <span>lorem ipsum<br/> lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.row > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvLJV/4/)

---

**Another way.**

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn">...</div>
    <img src="http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504stolze/test_1.jpg" /> <span>lorem ipsum<br/> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.row > * {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30p;
    background-color: red;
}

.row { display: table-row; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvLJV/7/)

Comment: Your example doesn't work for long texts. If you replace "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum" with much longer text then it will be moved under the button and image: http://jsfiddle.net/SvLJV/5/

Comment: Then add width(or max-width if you like) to the span element... http://jsfiddle.net/SvLJV/6/

Comment: It's better but I would like to adjust width of span automatically to remaining space. So if there is 600px for text than I would like to have `span` width = 600px; If page is narrower and there is only 200px left for text I would like to have width of span = 200px.

Comment: It works only if I set width and height of button. In other case button will be expanded to cover whole cell. Following code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SvLJV/8/. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your span a width. That would force the line breaks in your "a" example.

#### HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="btn">BUTTON</div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" /><span>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>

</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.header {
    width: 500px;
    background: dimgrey;
}
.btn, img, span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abN39/1

Comment: Is it possible to do this without specifying width for `span` element?  I would like to adjust `span` width automatically to remaining space in header. This is my main problem.

Comment: Hmm, is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ardok/7vRB2/

I mean, it's still messy, but I don't know whether it's closer to what you want it to be

Comment: It's nice but your example requires padding value. I don't know what is the size of the image so I don't know what padding should I set.